# Angular 5 prevent adding props to class

Tags: class, typescript, angular5, extend

I have this class

```
export class Alpha {
     propAlpha?:string;

     constructor(){
     }

     setProp(key: string, value: string) {
        this[key] = value;
     }

}
```

Some rest call gives me an object (response) like this:

```
{
    propAlpha: "foo",
    _someUnwanted: "bar"
}
```

I need to push only valid props of this object into Alpha, so I did

```
let myAlpha = new Alpha();
_.each(Object.keys(response), key => {
    validProp(response[key]) && myAlpha.setProp(key, response[key]);
    /**
     * validProp() checks if value matches some criteria.
     * So even if "propAlpha" is in "Alpha" it may be 
     * excluded for some other reason!
     */
});
```

the problem is that `_someUnwanted` is added to my class.
How can I prevent that?

I'd need to check which keys are in Alpha..

maybe like this?

```
if(key in myAlpha) {
   myAlpha.setProp(key, response[key]);
}
```

Comment: are you sure that your `validProp` function takes the value and not the key ? kinda makes no sense to me. Do `validProp(key)` instead of `validProp(response[key])`

Comment: It's correct, I do some checks to check if the value can be used inside the Alpha class...

Comment: @Richard What I mean is that even if `propAlpha` is in Alpha, it could be excluded for other reasons...And that's why `propAlpha` is marked with the `?` in `Alpha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Different approach that doesn't require declaring separate enum is to declare class members inside it's constructor. Then your `Alpha` class would look like this:

```
export class Alpha {
     constructor(public propAlpha?: string){}

     setProp(key: string, value: string) {
        if (key in this) this[key] = value;
     }
}
```

assigning properties wouldn't change

```
_.each(Object.keys(response), key => {
    validProp(response[key]) && myAlpha.setProp(key, response[key]);
});
```

Comment: You're right. I finally tried this and it works like charm.

Answer (score 0):

Really awful but I solved by doing this:

```
export enum AlphaPublicKeys {
    propAlpha
}

let myAlpha = new Alpha();
_.each(Object.keys(response), key => {

    if(key in AlphaPublicKeys){
        validProp(response[key]) && myAlpha.setProp(key, response[key]);
    }
    /**
     * validProp() checks if value matches some criteria.
     * So even if "propAlpha" is in "Alpha" it may be 
     * excluded for some other reason!
     */
});
```

Hope this helps!